# sql query not fetching a row according to the condition

Tags: php, sql

I'am trying to fetch a row according to the data posted by a user using php.
following is the code.
is their some syntax error?

```
   Poll name: <input type="text" name="question" /><br />

    $question=$_POST['question'];

      $sql = "INSERT INTO poll_question(question)
       VALUES('" . $_POST['question'] . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $query=mysql_query("select * from poll_question where question = '$question'");

    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
```

since the value of numrows is still 0 , no row is being fetched. where is the problem?
i have connected to database and the "insert" query is working well , only the select query isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

check with `mysql-error()` what the error is throwing with the PHP engine. I think you are not connecting the database.

```
 //connect the databse

 $question=$_POST['question'];
   $q=mysql_query("select * from poll_question where question='$question'") or die(mysql_error());                  
  if($q)     //check the $q have any value
  {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO poll_question(question)
   VALUES('" . $_POST['question'] . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

   // query for fetching records
     $query=mysql_query("select * from poll_question where question = '$question'") or die(mysql_error()); 

     $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
     if($numrows)
   {  
     echo "have rows!";
   }
   else
 {  
 echo "does not have rows";

}
}
else

{
echo " question is already exist";

}
    // form part

 ?>


   Poll name: <input type="text" name="question" /><br />
   <input type-"submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: I edited the my code. You can use it now. If select query is not running, there should be syntax or query errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the database connection to execute the query. For example,

```
// Connect to the database
$dbc = mysqli_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'database');

$sql = "query text";

// pass the query to the database connection
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

// close the database connection when you're done
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: i have already connected to the database . The insert query is being executed without any error. only the select query is not working.